# Can we use custom directive which behaves as attribute with html input tag in angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, custom-directive

We are trying to enable a feature in html input tag using angular1.x custom directive as attribute,will it work? As per my research i have seen everywhere that custom directive which behaves as attribute always works with div tag.Please give some pointers.we don't want to assign anything into ng-model.we have created a directive which we want to use with input tag as attribute.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: You can use custom directive as an attribute. Ex.<test-info></test-info>

Comment: What would like to do with this directive?

Comment: krutkowski86-it will solve purpose for tyepahead feature.

Comment: Nikita- we want to use with input tag like <input my-dir="some value"></input>.yours is element way.